# semantic similarity between words using dynamic techniques(using wikipedia)

Tags: nlp, wikipedia, similarity

I wrote a program in python to find semantic similarity between words using word net. But I feel it is static. I want to give a dynamic approach to it. I want to access the definition of each word from wikipedia. How can I access the definition of a word like that? When I googled I found that by parsing wikipedia dump file we can get the defintion. But i don't know how to parse that. Does any one can implement a parser to get the definiton of word from dumped file. Is this the only way? Method is true.

Comment: Wikipedia generally has whole articles about subjects, not just the definition.

Comment: but i got 1 ieee paper explaining the same concept. But they are not saying how to take the definitions. wikipedia dump file contains small descriptions of its articles.  @svick

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to reinvent the wheels. Researchers in the University of Waikato set up a very good Wikipedia data mining service, called [WikipediaMiner](http://wikipedia-miner.cms.waikato.ac.nz/).

> This package converts regular Wikipedia dumps into MySql database format and provides an object-oriented access to parts of Wikipedia like articles, disambiguation pages and hyperlinks. Wikipedia Miner also implements an algorithm for computing semantic relatedness between articles that [Maui](http://code.google.com/p/maui-indexer/wiki/InsideMaui) uses to disambiguate documents to Wikipedia articles and for computing semantic features.

They also exposed various API on top of that.
For example, if you want to **get the definition** of `Logistic Regression`, just use their `exploreArticle` API:

> http://wikipedia-miner.cms.waikato.ac.nz/services/exploreArticle?title=logistic%20regression&definition=true

The response xml looks like:

```
<message service="/services/exploreArticle" id="226631" title="Logistic regression">
<request>
  <param name="title">logistic regression</param>
  <param name="definition">true</param>
</request>
<definition><![CDATA[In <a href="http://www.en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistics">statistics</a>, <b>logistic regression</b> (sometimes called the <b>logistic model</b> or <b><a href="http://www.en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit">logit</a> model</b>) is used for prediction of the <a href="http://www.en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability">probability</a> of occurrence of an event by fitting data to a logit function <a href="http://www.en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic function">logistic curve</a>.]]>
</definition>
</message>
```

To **compare the semantic similarity between words**, you can try their `compare` API.

E.g., comparing `kiwi` with `takahe`, you use below API call:

> http://wikipedia-miner.cms.waikato.ac.nz/services/compare?term1=kiwi&term2=takahe&disambiguationDetails&connections&snippets

[Here](http://wikipedia-miner.cms.waikato.ac.nz/wiki/Wiki.jsp?page=Article%20relatedness%20measures) is some more details about the algorithm they use for their relatedness measure.

You can also host your own wikipediaMiner service (details [here](http://wikipedia-miner.cms.waikato.ac.nz/wiki/Wiki.jsp?page=Installation%20and%20configuration)).
Find more about how to use their service at [here](http://wikipedia-miner.cms.waikato.ac.nz/services/). Their related publications are [here](http://wikipedia-miner.sourceforge.net/publications.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're actually looking for a *thesaurus*, not wikipedia. Some of those are available as machine-readable corpora. I have to admit, however, that textual definitions don't seem like a good source of information for determining word similarity, except in some specialized cases.

These is a substantial body of work on word similarity measures, so instead of reinventing the wheel one could look into the state-of-the-art techniques and/or tools. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_similarity) mentions some of those.